# Different ways to run a python program through gvim text editor in cmd [for windows]

Tags: python, windows, vim

I want to execute my python program through gvim in windows, but using the command `!python main.py` it can't find the file in the current directory, so how do I run it in the cmd to that location, not for just python but for all the languages like c, java also...

Answer (score 0):

the variable `%` contains the full path of the file try

```
!python %
```

Comment: It also gives me Errno 2 no such file or directory

Comment: can you post the exact error message?

Comment: cmd /c python E:\Code Editors CS50 Programming with python test.pyd 
python: can't open file 'E:\\Code': [Errno 2] No such file or directory shell returned 2
Hit any key to close this window...